# Is there a way to convert json to Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a json string like shown below. Is there a way to convert this to dataframe

```
structure("{\n  \"a1\": \"2022-05-04\",\n  \"inputType\": true,\n  \"valDe\": \"2022-05-04\",\n  \"MainNavBar\": \"V\",\n  \"btna\": 0,\n  \"df\": [\"CRP\", \"AS\", \"OOL\", \"GOT\", \"ANCY\"],\n  \"fd\": {},\n  \"fd.1\": {}\n}", class = "json")

{
  "a1": "2022-05-04",
  "inputType": true,
  "valDe": "2022-05-04",
  "MainNavBar": "V",
  "btna": 0,
  "df": ["CP", "AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY"],
  "fd": {},
  "fd.1": {}
}
```

Expected output

```
df1

a1          inputType   valDe     MainNavBar  btna      df                               fd     fd.1
2022-05-04     true   2022-05-04     V        0     c("CP", "AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY")  NULL  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
json_text %>%
  fromJSON %>%
  bind_cols
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  a1         inputType valDe      MainNavBar  btna df   
  <chr>      <lgl>     <chr>      <chr>      <int> <chr>
1 2022-05-04 TRUE      2022-05-04 V              0 CRP  
2 2022-05-04 TRUE      2022-05-04 V              0 AS   
3 2022-05-04 TRUE      2022-05-04 V              0 OOL  
4 2022-05-04 TRUE      2022-05-04 V              0 GOT  
5 2022-05-04 TRUE      2022-05-04 V              0 ANCY
```

Or you could add `%>% tidyr::nest(df)` to put the values of `df` into a list within that column:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  a1         inputType valDe      MainNavBar  btna data            
  <chr>      <lgl>     <chr>      <chr>      <int> <list>          
1 2022-05-04 TRUE      2022-05-04 V              0 <tibble [5 × 1]>
```

Here's the output as an object you can inspect:

```
output = structure(list(a1 = "2022-05-04", inputType = TRUE, valDe = "2022-05-04", 
MainNavBar = "V", btna = 0L, data = list(structure(list(df = c("CRP", 
"AS", "OOL", "GOT", "ANCY")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L)))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`
```

Comment: Thanks. But i did not get your last statement. Could you reproduce please